# Vim grep setting issue (getting FINDSTR: Cannot open System32 when using findstr, and can't figure out how to set an external grep)

Tags: vim, grep, findstr

I'm using Gvim 7.4 in Windows 7 x64. When I grep for anything, I get the error:

```
FINDSTR: Cannot open System32
```

I've looked it up and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108588/vim-greps-wildcard-doesnt-work-in-windows). I think my situation is different. I don't know what's causing the error. I don't want to use the internal grep in vim. I either want findstr or just normal grep (The answer didn't cover setting up the external grep, it just mentioned that it's doable) From what I understood (correct me if I'm wrong) when I do grep in vim, it locates whatever it is my OS's searching tool and uses that instead. So I should be good to go using findstr, why isn't it working?

I eventually gave up on findstr and installed [UnxUtils](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) to `C:\Linux` But I couldn't figure out how to set vim's external grepping tool to use `C:\Linux\grep.exe` - I know it has to do with `grepprg` but I'm not sure how, I tried setting it directly set `grepprg="C:/Linux/grep.exe"` (or `grep.exe -n` for that matter - with and without the `.exe`) but that didn't work, every time I grep for something like `grep someString .` `it says someString is not recognized as an internal or external command`. The doc is a big vague on the subject. How can I set vim's external grep to my installed one?

Thanks.

---

EDIT:

I also tried adding the 'grep.exe' to one of my `$PATH` directories (system32) - and do `set grepprg=grep\ -nH` but now when I grep it says `grep is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Comment: Hi Try something like the following which works for me  :let Grep_Path = 'C:\gnuwin32\bin\grep.exe'
:let Fgrep_Path = 'C:\gnuwin32\bin\fgrep.exe'
:let Egrep_Path = 'C:\gnuwin32\bin\egrep.exe'
:let Agrep_Path = 'C:\gnuwin32\bin\agrep.exe'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your 64-bit System32 directory is where findstr lives, but if you're running a 32-bit Vim, it won't actually see that directory. Instead it sees the c:\windows\Syswow64 directory due to a feature of Windows. But you can probably force Vim to look in the "real" System32 folder, by adding it to your path in your .vimrc:

```
let $PATH.=';C:\Windows\Sysnative'
```

Comment: Thanks you pointed me to the right place. I added ';c:\windows\Syswow64' and that was it. But strange thing, findstr.exe was in both system32 and Syswow64... system32 was added in $PATH, hmm...

Answer (score 0):

So I had to copy grep.exe to my `Vim installation/Vim74` instead of`C:/Windows/system32` and also do `set grepprg=grep\ -nH`